# how can I hide resources?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a page where it shows the resource created by other users but hide the resources created by current_user. is there a method or certain way in which I can do so?

```
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @examples = Example.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @creator_examples = Example.where(creator: current_user).order("created_at DESC") <---hide this!!!
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply manipulate your `where` clause into something like this:

```
def index
  @examples = Example.all.order("created_at DESC")
  @creator_examples = @examples.where.not(id: current_user.id)
end
```

This is for rails 4, if you're using rails 3

```
@creator_examples = Example.where("id != ?", current_user.id)
```

*Note* -> Example.all in rails 3 returns an array so you can't chain it with `where`